# Possible to make callout during package uninstall script

Tags: managed-package

I would like to make a callout on package uninstall (from a [package uninstall script](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_uninstall_script.htm)) to notify an external application that the package was uninstalled. The page says it's not possible.

> The uninstall script has the following restrictions. You can’t use it to initiate batch, scheduled, and future jobs, to access Session IDs, or to **perform callouts**.

Is there any alternative way to notify my external application that this package was uninstalled?

Comment: I see you can send an email in your uninstall script. Why don't you send the email to your dev org long email address to create a Case in that org and then on that Case, create a callout? Just an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do it from within that org, as the page says. Create a trigger on the License object in your [LMA](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_intro.htm) if you want to detect uninstall scenarios.